# Pilha não retira os valores

Tags: c

Olá, estou fazendo uma Pilha (LIFO) e a mesma não substitui os valores por 0 na hora de retirar os valores da pilha. Isso foi uma maneira que encontrei para "remover" os dados da mesma e a exibição é mostrada com os valores "1.9".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAMANHO_MAX_PILHA 10

typedef struct {
  int totalElementos;
  float pilha[TAMANHO_MAX_PILHA];
} PILHA;

PILHA *CriarPilha() {
  PILHA *ppilha;
  ppilha = (PILHA *) malloc(sizeof(PILHA));
  ppilha->totalElementos = 0;
  return ppilha;
}

void Listar(PILHA *ppilha) {
  int totalElementos = ppilha->totalElementos;
  int indiceTopoPilha = totalElementos - 1;
  for (int indiceVetor = indiceTopoPilha; indiceVetor >= 0 ; indiceVetor--) {
    float  elemento = ppilha->pilha[indiceVetor];
    printf("Posição %i = %f \n", indiceVetor + 1, elemento);
  }
}

float Push(PILHA *ppilha, float novoElemento) {
  int totalElementos = ppilha->totalElementos;
  if(totalElementos == TAMANHO_MAX_PILHA){
    printf("Pilha Cheia");
  } else {
      for (int indiceVetor = totalElementos; indiceVetor <= TAMANHO_MAX_PILHA - 1; indiceVetor++) {
        ppilha->pilha[indiceVetor] = novoElemento;
        ppilha->totalElementos++;
      }
    }
}

float Pop(PILHA *ppilha) {
  int totalElementos = ppilha->totalElementos;
  int indiceTopoPilha = totalElementos - 1;
  if(totalElementos != 0) {
  for (int indiceVetor = indiceTopoPilha; indiceVetor < 0 ; indiceVetor--) {
      ppilha->pilha[indiceVetor] = 0.5;
      ppilha->totalElementos--;
    }
  } else {
      printf("Pilha Vazia");
    }
  }

void main() {
  PILHA *ppilha;
  float novoElemento = 1.9;

  ppilha = CriarPilha();
  Push(ppilha, novoElemento);
  Listar(ppilha);
  printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  Pop(ppilha);
  Listar(ppilha);
}
```

Comment: Qual é a pergunta ?

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo o seu racíocinio, segue um código simplificado (e testado) que implementa uma pilha `LIFO` de valores `float`.

```
/* ****************************************************************** */
/* *                           pilha_float.c                        * */
/* ****************************************************************** */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define PILHA_MAX_TAM        (10)

#define SUCESSO              (0)
#define ERRO_PILHA_CHEIA     (-1)
#define ERRO_PILHA_VAZIA     (-2)


typedef struct pilha_s pilha_t;

struct pilha_s
{
    float item[ PILHA_MAX_TAM ];
    int qtd;
};


void pilha_inicializar( pilha_t * p )
{
    memset( p, 0, sizeof(pilha_t) );
}


int pilha_push_item( pilha_t * p, float n )
{
    if( p->qtd == PILHA_MAX_TAM )
        return ERRO_PILHA_CHEIA;

    p->item[ p->qtd++ ] = n;

    return SUCESSO;
}


float pilha_pop_item( pilha_t * p )
{
    if( p->qtd == 0 )
        return ERRO_PILHA_VAZIA;

    return p->item[ --p->qtd ];
}


void pilha_listar_itens( pilha_t * p )
{
    int i = 0;

    if( !p->qtd )
    {
        printf("Pilha Vazia!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf( "Pilha:\n" );

    for( i = p->qtd - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        printf( "   Posicao %d / Valor: %f\n", i, p->item[i] );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    pilha_t p;

    pilha_inicializar( &p );

    /* Empilha 4 Constantes Matematicas... */

    pilha_push_item( &p, 3.14159 ); /* Push PI */
    pilha_push_item( &p, 2.71828 ); /* Push Euler's Number */
    pilha_push_item( &p, 1.61803 ); /* Push Golden Ratio */
    pilha_push_item( &p, 0.66274 ); /* Push Laplace Limit */

    pilha_listar_itens( &p );

    /* Desempilha apenas 2 constantes... */

    pilha_pop_item( &p ); /* Pop Laplace Limit */
    pilha_pop_item( &p ); /* Pop Golden Ratio */

    pilha_listar_itens( &p );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
Pilha:
   Posicao 3 / Valor: 0.662740
   Posicao 2 / Valor: 1.618030
   Posicao 1 / Valor: 2.718280
   Posicao 0 / Valor: 3.141590
Pilha:
   Posicao 1 / Valor: 2.718280
   Posicao 0 / Valor: 3.141590
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Olha, pelo o seu código fica difícil ter que mexer nele todo para fazer Last In, First Out, acho que se você colocar um marcador na struct para saber se na posição foi dado um push ou pop, talvez ajude a saber quem é o último elemento do vetor. Uma solução mais elegante seria fazer uma lista encadeada, onde a raiz da lista tem o ponteiro para último elemento, quando fizer um push, você coloca este como o último da raiz e como anterior o último, quando fizer o pop, coloca o anterior como o último da raiz e da free nele.

Elemento1 <--- Elemento2 <--- Elemento3 <--- Raiz.
Abraços.

Comment: É um exercício de Faculdade, matéria de Estrutura de Dados, elementos com 0 = Posição Vazia

Comment: Cria uma função que inicia todos elementos com 0, a cada push você busca o último elemento com 0 e substitui o valor, a cada pop pega o elemento anterior ao 0 encontrado e zera o valor.